# Cannot open Mongo shell on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed MongoDB on Ununtu 14.

How do I open the its shell?

I followed this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/, which told me to run ./bin/mongo in my Mongo installation directory. Afaik the Mongo installation directory in my computer is var/lib/mongodb, but I don't see any "bin" directory in there, just the following files and directories: journal,  local.0,  local.ns,  mongod.lock,  storage.bson,  _tmp.

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Comment: What's your MongoDB version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder you are looking into is not the mongodb installation folder, but where it stores the data.

If you have installed mongodb through package manager, you can do (to make sure mongodb is running):

```
sudo service mongod start
```

And then just use the

`mongo`

command, as it should already be on your path

You can check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/client/) for more information

Comment: you mean "sudo service mongod start". I typed it and got: "start: Job is already running: mongod". I can run the service from any path and it doesn't make me enter into Mongo shell.

Comment: then you can just use the "mongo" command to get to the shell